# Only fire one click event when polyline is clicked in Google Maps (v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, click, dom-events

For Google Maps V3, I have some code that created a marker when a polyline was clicked.  I also have some code that creates a marker when the map is clicked.

***Earlier today***, when I clicked on the polyline, only one marker was created (I'm guessing it didn't fire a map-click event).  Now tonight, I have not changed my code at all, and it is firing both the polyline click event and the map click event and creating two markers.  I have no clue if Google changed their maps API between earlier today and now or what, but I need to cancel the click event for the map when the polyline is clicked.  Does anyone know how to do this?

***EDIT: August 5th*** Okay what the heck Google!  Now it's back to not firing a map event when the polyline is clicked.  Pick a way and stick with it!  I am very sure this issue is not related to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate click event for your polyline.  However, it is hard for the map to determine whether you clicked the map or the polyline.  In the case of a polygon, the API should not fire the map event.

If not, you may want to implement some sort of state pattern to block code that shouldn't execute.